# Register Callback URL moves API

Tags: android, callback

I am trying to implement the storyline notifications part in the Moves application api. https://dev.moves-app.com/docs/api_notifications

I building my application on Android. I was confused about how to register a callback URL to receive notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You should own your own server and you should have a callback URL and you should give this url in your console to the Moves App.

After you do that, they will notify you by calling this URL with specified parameters. And then you can save that parameters and act whatever you like after this.